# Trying to integrate function gives "loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Symbol"

Tags: python, numpy, math, numerical-integration

My packages:

```
from pylab import plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sympy as sy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
from pylab import mpl
import scipy.integrate as sci
import scipy.stats as scs
import pandas_datareader as web
import statsmodels.api as sm
import scipy.optimize as spo
from yahoo_fin import options
from dawp import *
import math
import sys
import yfinance as yf
```

I define a function:

```
def Hh(n, x):
    if n == -1:
        return np.exp(-x**2 / 2)
    elif n == 0:
        return math.sqrt(2*math.pi) * scs.norm.cdf(-x)
    else:
        return (Hh(n-2, x) - x * Hh(n-1, x)) / n
```

Now I would like to define another function that integrates the `Hh` function with respect to `x`. I try to do it like this:

```
def I(n, c, a, b, d):
    return sci.quad(np.exp(a*x) * Hh(n, b*x - d), c, np.inf)
```

but I get this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: 'Symbol' object has no attribute 'exp'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-796991ea4106> in <module>
----> 1 I(1,1,1,1,1)

<ipython-input-72-0a67e7ee1499> in I(n, c, a, b, d)
      1 def I(n,c,a,b,d):
----> 2     return sci.quad(np.exp(a*x)*Hh(n,b*x-d), c, np.inf)

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Symbol which has no callable exp method
```

What should I change to get the correct result and with respect to `x`?

Comment: What are `sci` and `scs`?

Comment: I edit my post and add package

Comment: What would be an example for you a Parameter?

Comment: Why can you not use the sympy integration function?

Comment: You're attempting to use functions that cannot make use of symbols. My advice is to define ```x``` as a symbol, manually code the norm, the square root and the exponential functions with respect to ```x```, and then make use of ```sympy.integrate()``` to integrate the output of ```Hh()```.

Comment: Don't mix `sympy` with `numpy` and other numeric packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the indefinite integral of each of your conditionals as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

x = sp.symbols('x')

def Hh(n):

    if n == -1:
        fx = sp.exp(-x**2 / 2)

    elif n == 0:
        fx = ((2*np.pi)**(1/2)) * (sp.exp((-x**2)/2) / (2*np.pi)**(1/2))

    return fx

print (sp.integrate(Hh(n=0), x))
```

There may be a sympy function that can handle norm (used when `n == 0`), but I have never used one (you'll see that I've just coded the formula in).
Furthermore, be sure to use `sp.exp()` rather than `math.exp()` or `np.exp()` when dealing with symbolically defined exponential functions.

If you need to determine the definite integral, take a look at:
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html

I've not put in your `else` statement to save time, but the above should still apply.